# Why body behind modal is still scrolling?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, overflow

I have this code, I thought it is straightforward, but not. Content behind is still scrolling when popup appeared.

```js
const Modal = ({ children, title, completion, isMyFlex, ...rest }: Props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }, [])
```

Comment: r u sure what is being scrolled is body?

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible code. On codesandbox for example